# Create list of lists containing tuples at start and end of sublist

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a flattened list l something like this

```
l = [(2.0000001192092896, 3.3999999761581421), [4, 3], (1.9999999701976776, 1.7999999821186066), (0.875, 1.125), [-1, 0], [-1, 4], (1.5, 3.5)].
```

I want to create a list of lists containing tuples at the start and end something like this:

```
l' = [[(2.0000001192092896, 3.3999999761581421), [4, 3], (1.9999999701976776, 1.7999999821186066)],[(1.9999999701976776, 1.7999999821186066),(0.875, 1.125)], [(0.875, 1.125), [-1, 0], [-1, 4], (1.5, 3.5)],[(1.5, 3.5),(2.0000001192092896, 3.3999999761581421)]]
```

`l'` contains all the tuples and the list between them if any.

I was trying to do the same using following code but not able to implement successfully:

```
full_list = []
state = 0
for ind,value in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(value, tuple):
        if state == 0:
            state = 1
            inner_list = []
            if ind == len(l) - 1:
                k = 0
            else:
                k = ind + 1
            j = l[k]
            if isinstance(j,tuple):
                full_list.append(inner_list)
                inner_list.append(j)
        else:
            state = 0 
    inner_list.append(value)     

print(full_list)
```

Can someone suggest some other alternative ?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Which tuples do you want at the start and the end? And which lists will go between them? The second list in `l'` has no list in it whereas the third list in it has two lists between the start and ending tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to clean things up a bit. No need for checking if it's a list as there are only tuples and lists this way too.

```
l = [(2.0000001192092896, 3.3999999761581421), [4, 3], (1.9999999701976776, 1.7999999821186066), (0.875, 1.125), [-1, 0], [-1, 4], (1.5, 3.5)]
full_list = []
inner_list = []
for value in l:
    if isinstance(value, tuple):
        inner_list.append(value)
        if len(inner_list) > 0:
            full_list.append(inner_list)
            inner_list = []
    else:
        inner_list.append(value)

print(full_list)
```

This will print:

```
[[(2.0000001192092896, 3.399999976158142), [4, 3], (1.9999999701976776, 1.7999999821186066)], [(0.875, 1.125), [-1, 0], [-1, 4], (1.5, 3.5)]]
```

Comment: What is i in this case ?

Comment: It was supposed to be `inner_list` Thanks for asking! Edited my answer

Comment: thanks for answering but I want a list something like l', the list your code gives is the one I already have.

Comment: Another mistype in my code. I forgot to append the value to inner_list before appending to full_list and resetting inner_list. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take indices where `tuples` are present then `zip` them and use list comprehension as:

```
tup_index = [index for index,value in enumerate(l) if isinstance(value,tuple)]
full_list = [l[first:last+1] for first,last in zip(tup_index[::2],tup_index[1::2])]

print(full_list)

[[(2.0000001192092896, 3.399999976158142),[4, 3],(1.9999999701976776, 1.7999999821186066)],
 [(0.875, 1.125), [-1, 0], [-1, 4], (1.5, 3.5)]]
```

Or if the list contains odd number of tuples then:

```
if len(tup_index)%2==0:
    full_list = [l[first:last+1] for first,last in zip(tup_index[::2],tup_index[1::2])]
else:
    tup_index.append(len(l)+1)
    full_list = [l[first:last+1] for first,last in zip(tup_index[::2],tup_index[1::2])]
```

Comment: Sandeep thanks for answering but I do not get list like l'. This list is the one I already have.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra `'` is a special character used with strings. So, you will never have a variable named `l'`. Try different naming convention. Thank you.

Comment: I mean to say that I want to have the other list as mentioned in the question.

Comment: it's still the same !!

Comment: @AshutoshMishra the output contains tuples at the start and end for each list inside the main list.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Please [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if any of the solutions provided your required result.